# findコマンドのオプション引数のハイフンが一つの理由

Tags: linux

unix系コマンドのオプション引数の多くはハイフン2つで先行され、ハイフン一つはその省略形となるかと思います。
( `--force` と `-f` など )
対してfindのオプション引数は `-name` や `-exec` など一つのハイフンになっています。
これには何か、由来や思想があるのでしょうか。

我ながら子供みたいな質問だとおもいますが、どうしても気になってしまいました。
ご存知の方おられたら何卒ご教示ください。

Comment: [Why do Linux command line scripts use '-' and '--' as a parameter prefix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447200/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ハイフン2つで始まるオプション形式は、GNU ProjectがUNIX互換コマンドをリリースしたころに現れたものです。

Linuxが広まる前のUNIX OSに付属のコマンドは、オプションをハイフン1つで始めるのが慣習でしたので、
そのころから存在する`find`コマンドもオプションはハイフン1つにしているのでしょう。

＃Linux distribution(CentOS, Ubuntu等)では、`find`もGNU Project製の互換コマンドですが。
＃Linux distributionで見かけるコマンドの多くはGNU Project製のコマンドなので、質問のように感じるものと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。納得できました。